# Hide/Show div and change class in span with Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using very simple function to hide entire div when clicked and display comments block instead.

Instead of hiding entire div, what I need to do is keep it as it is when clicked, display comment block, but change the class in the span from class="icon expand" to class="icon abate" and hide only "Click here to leave a comment or view what our customers are saying." line so that if it is clicked again it would do the opposite.

here is my script

```
function myfunc_showComments() {
    if ( typeof jQuery != 'undefined' ) {
        $('#hidecomments').remove();
    }
var commentsParams ={
categoryID: 'Widgets',
streamID: '<?php echo $streamID ?>',
containerID: 'commentsDiv',
}
gigya.services.socialize.showCommentsUI(conf,commentsParams);
}
</script>
<!-- end #review --></div>
<div id="hidecomments">
<div class="button_3" onClick="myfunc_showComments()"><span class="icon expand"></span><h2>Comment &amp; Rate this <span><?php echo $widget_title ?></span></h2><br />Click here to leave a comment or view what our customers are saying.
</div>
</div>
```

any suggestions or help is highly appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to put the "Click here..." text that you want to show and hide inside a div of its own:

```
<div id="hidecomments">
    <div class="button_3"><span class="icon expand"></span>
        <h2>Comment &amp; Rate this <span><?php echo $widget_title ?></span></h2>
        <br />
        <div class="instruction">
             Click here to leave a comment or view what our customers are saying.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...so that it is easier to manipulate from your JavaScript code. Note that I've also removed the inline `onClick="myfunc_showComments()"` part, because you can just directly bind the handler form your script as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".button_3").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find("span.icon").toggleClass("expand abate");
        $this.find("div.instruction").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

The [`.toggleClass()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) adds or removes the specified classes depending on whether they're already there; it can add and remove at the same time so there's no need to manually code an if test to see what the current class is.

The [`.slideToggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) is just one of several options that hide an element that is visible or show an element that is not visible. Other options include `.toggle()` or `.fadeToggle()`.

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/cRjCN/

Note that the document ready wrapper is not needed if the script appears after the elements in question.

Comment: ok this is working to the point where it is now replacing the class in the span and expanding comments block, but now I need to add the opposite so that if is clicked again it should go back to the defaults.

Comment: Actually I have just noticed that that particular part does go to the default status, but comments are not being hidden and remain expanded

Comment: In my demo the comments are alternately hidden and visible with each click. Are you talking about something you tried in your real project, or...? You _did_ notice that my solution involved a minor change to your html structure to wrap the comments in a div (the new div I added had `class="instruction"`)?

Comment: so what do you think?

Comment: I think that you haven't given any new information since my previous comment so I don't know what you're now asking.

Comment: What link? Posted where?

Comment: You have to remove the inline `onClick="spr123_showComments()"`, get rid of the `function spr123_showComments()` and just use the JavaScript I showed in my answer to bind the click handler. (The way you currently have it every click binds an additional click handler.)

Answer (score 0):

use [jQuery prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) do it like this `$(yourselector).prop('class','icon abate')`;

Edit:

```
$(".button_3").click(function(e) {
    $("span.icon.expand").prop('class','icon abate');
});
```

just add the code block above inside `<script>` tags inside your html `body` tag. preferably before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: what should be "yourselector" when used for changing class in the <span class="icon expand"></span>?